# chktex: who knows about return code

Tags: chktex

I realized right now that chktex has return code 0 only if not even a warning is displayed.
With warnings seems to be 2.
What about other return codes? 1 for instance?
The documentation keeps this secret.

Comment: The code does

`* Count how warnings or errors we've found, and
* update the return code with the worst. */

switch (LaTeXMsgs[Error].Type)

case etWarn:
   WarnPrint++;
   FoundErr = max(FoundErr, EXIT_WARNINGS);
   break;
case etErr:
   ErrPrint++;
   FoundErr = max(FoundErr, EXIT_ERRORS);
   break;
case etMsg:
   break;

...

 ret = FindErr(ReadBuffer, CurStkLine(&InputStack));
   if ( ret != EXIT_SUCCESS ) {
     retval = ret;
...
    return retval;
`

so it looks like the exit code is a warning count, but I get 2 or 0 in all cases

Comment: Ah thank you for pointing.. FindErrs.c in https://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/chktex.git. 
I am not enough into C to find out whats going on in detail. 
So 2 means: at least one error or warning. 1 does not occur and 0 means all ok. 
At least that is a conjecture.

Comment: some reverse engineering seems to show: 
1: error in operation, e.g. invalid option 
3: error found but not case 1; error ist warning declared as error via -e<number>
2: warning found but either case 1 nor case 2. 
0: neither of the cases above, i.e. operation ok, neither error nor warning found.